# Do something after jQuery animations complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a jQuery animation where 4 divs, their background images are animated at the same time with different speeds, so one will complete after another randomly.

Now I want to execute a function after 3 seconds from the last completed animation.

```
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#div-1').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 8000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $('#div-2').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 10000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $('#div-3').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 9000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $('#div-4').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 7000, 'easeInOutQuart');
}, function(){
    // Do something
});
```

The problem here is that it will execute "Do something" whithout waiting for the 4 animations to complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second will always take the longest, so you could just do

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#div-1').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 8000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $('#div-2').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 10000, 'easeInOutQuart', function() {
        // all should be done, as this one is the longest running animation
        setTimeout(function() {
             // wait an additional 3 seconds
        }, 3000);
    });
    $('#div-3').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 9000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $('#div-4').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 7000, 'easeInOutQuart');

});
```

if you want to wait on all of them, jQuery animations can return promises, which could be used like

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var arr = [
        $('#div-1').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 8000, 'easeInOutQuart').promise(),
        $('#div-2').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 10000, 'easeInOutQuart').promise(),
        $('#div-3').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 9000, 'easeInOutQuart').promise(),
        $('#div-4').animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, 7000, 'easeInOutQuart').promise()
    ];

    $.when.apply($, arr).then(function() {
        // all complete
        setTimeout(function() {
             // wait an additional 3 seconds
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

If you intend on doing this on many elements, something like this might be useful

```
$.fn.anim = function(speed) {
 return this.animate({'background-position-y': '4000'}, speed, 'easeInOutQuart').promise();
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.when.apply($, [
        $('#div-1').anim(8000),
        $('#div-2').anim(10000),
        $('#div-3').anim(9000),
        $('#div-4').anim(7000)
    ]).then(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
             // wait an additional 3 seconds
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```